# How to get data like tinder of unique users each times

Tags: php, database, eloquent, backend, laravel-8

I am planning to build a dating site. but want some suggestion in getting display users data. In my project, there will be no swipe feature instead we use multiple buttons to send different req. to users.

My Motive for the project is to get the nearest active users first according to interests. All of the modules are done only showing the nearest users algorithm is on hold.

we have to calculate the user's distance from the logged-in user location based on latitude and longitude. Then see the active users who are most close to the logged-in user.

I have stored logged-in users' latitude and longitude in DB.

This is a web project built in laravel-8.

I have to fetch 1 user record at a time after getting the nearest active user.

Note: Main I have to get a solution to get the next user on each click. I have tried it with pagination but that is not a good practice. I need some suggestion to other method to get 1 next user data at a time.

Comment: You could simply fetch multiple users at once and then just show them one by one using JS. Another alternative would be to use the same query, fetching the closest user each time but add a list of user id's to exclude (by storing the users already fetched in a session or similar).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout [inRandomOrder()](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#random-ordering).Seems like it can be handled in one query. Further you can create api to get new user each time.

Try this:

```
$randomUser = DB::table('users')->whereNotIn('id',$userIdArrayAlreadyShown)->inRandomOrder()->first();
```